# Where is the style for @android:stye/Theme.Dialog defined

Tags: android

Where is the style attributes for `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` defined? Also is there any central place where all the attributes for the "style element" is documented? I already looked at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) but it has `windowframe` and several attributes missing.

Comment: "android-sdks\platforms\android-17\data\res\values\themes.xml" <-- You mean here? found at your android sdk directory.

Comment: Yep. I guess that the one. PLease post it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it in your Android SDK directory, at `"android-sdks\platforms\android-17\data\res\values\themes.xml"`